# React Native Camera does not compile

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

Here is what i have done so far

> ```
> React-native init MyCamera
> cd MyCamera
> npm install react-native-camera --save
> npm install
> react-native link react-native-camera
> ```

But when i run the application it does not compile
check these screenshot of errors

running Android
  [image: running Android]
running iOS
[image: Running iOS]

Comment: Note how the instructions say ["mostly automatic install"](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera#mostly-automatic-install-with-react-native). You still need to do some other manual steps to complete the installation. Have you done all of them?

Comment: i have tried that for android but not for iOS yet. does not seem to work for android first of all.

Comment: @MichaelCheng thank you.. android part is configured nicely. but iOS has some issues.

Answer (score 1):

Automatic linking doesn't guarantee completely setting up a module if there are more than one module already added to the project. So , make sure `app/build.gradle` file has camera module added as project, and `project/build.gradle` file has the maven dependency for jitpack. Then see if App's `application file` has package added to the alreary existing list of packages. *Maven repo should be there in project's gradle file.*

Comment: okay it helped me setup android part.  but iOS is still giving me same error.